# How to refresh the JTable in gui from database?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Here i connect my database:

```
package org.connect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class dbconnect {

    public static Connection getConnectionvalue() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "kingdom");
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error" + e);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static Statement
    getStatementvalue() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "kingdom");
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error" + e);
        }
        return stmt;
    }
}
```

Here i created the frame and getting the database table values. And then i passed the resultset of table values to the Deptmodeltable

```
package org.frames.src;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.RowSetEvent;
import javax.sql.RowSetListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import org.connect.dbconnect;
import org.reports.master.TESTJASPER;
import org.table.model.DeptTableModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DeptFrame extends JFrame implements RowSetListener, ActionListener {

    Statement stmt = dbconnect.getStatementvalue();
    Connection con = dbconnect.getConnectionvalue();
    public static JTable table; // The table for displaying data
    public static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public static JPanel mainpanel, panel, panel1;
    public static JButton button;
    DeptTableModel depttm;

    public DeptFrame() throws SQLException {
        super("The Masters: Department");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    System.out.println("windowClosing" + sqle);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        );

        ResultSet rstable = getContentsOfTable();
        depttm = new DeptTableModel(rstable);

        table = new JTable(); // Displays the table
        table.setModel(depttm);
        table.setForeground(Color.gray);
        table.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setSize(300, 300);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        button = new JButton("ViewReport");

        button.addActionListener(this);
        mainpanel = new JPanel();

        panel1 = new JPanel();

        panel1.add(button);
        mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainpanel.add(scrollPane);
        mainpanel.add("South", panel1);
    }

    /**
     * @param args * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SQLException {
        DeptFrame df = new DeptFrame();
        df.add(mainpanel);
        df.setSize(700, 700);
        df.getContentPane().add(mainpanel);
        df.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ResultSet getContentsOfTable() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from M_department");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Query" + e);
        }
        return rs;
    }

    @Override
    public void cursorMoved(RowSetEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void rowChanged(RowSetEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void rowSetChanged(RowSetEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {         // TODO Auto-generated method stub         String action =
        e.getActionCommand();
        if (action.equals("ViewReport")) {
            String[] args = null;
            TESTJASPER.main(args);
            try {
                TESTJASPER.openPdf();
            } catch (IOException e1) {             // TODO
                Auto - generated catch block e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch
                    (InterruptedException e1) {             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i implements the table model listener and setting the JTable values

```
package org.table.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.RowSet;
import javax.sql.RowSetListener;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet;
import org.connect.dbconnect;
import org.frames.src.DeptFrame;

public class DeptTableModel implements TableModel {
    Statement stmt = dbconnect.getStatementvalue();
    Connection con = dbconnect.getConnectionvalue();
    static ResultSet rsdept;
    ResultSetMetaData metadata; // Additional information about the results
    int numcols, numrows;
    public OracleCachedRowSet ocrs;

    public ResultSet getDeptRowSet() {
        return rsdept;
    }

    public DeptTableModel(ResultSet rsarg) throws SQLException {
        this.rsdept = rsarg;
        this.metadata = this.rsdept.getMetaData();
        this.numcols = metadata.getColumnCount();
        ocrs = new OracleCachedRowSet();
        ocrs.populate(this.rsdept);
        ocrs.beforeFirst();
        this.numrows = 0;
        while (ocrs.next()) {
            this.numrows++;
        }
        ocrs.beforeFirst();
        //System.out.println(numrows);      //System.out.println(numcols);  }

    public void close() {
        try {
            rsdept.getStatement().close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Automatically close when we're garbage collected
     */
    protected void finalize() {
        close();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {         // TODO Auto - generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Class
    getColumnClass(int column) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return numcols;
    }

    @Override
    public String
    getColumnName(int column) {
        try {
            return this.metadata.getColumnLabel(column + 1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return numrows;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        try {
            ocrs.absolute(rowIndex + 1);
            Object o = ocrs.getObject(columnIndex + 1);
            if (o == null)
                return null;
            else
                return o.toString();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void
    removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {         // TODO Auto - generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        System.out.println("Calling setValueAt row " + row + ", column " + column + " value is" + value.toString());

        System.out.println(getColumnName(column));
        System.out.println(getValueAt(row, 0));
        String updateq = "update M_department set " + getColumnName(column) + "='" + value.toString()
                + "' where code = '" + getValueAt(row, 0) + "' ";
        System.out.println(updateq);
        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate(updateq);
            DeptFrame x = new DeptFrame();
            new DeptTableModel(x.getContentsOfTable());
        } catch (SQLException e) {             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but my jtable not getting refreshed after updating a row

Comment: fixing the formatting of the code would really help...

Comment: and you also have a huge sql injection case here:          `String updateq="update M_department set "+getColumnName(column)+"='"+value.toString()+"' where
    code='"+getValueAt(row,0)+"'";`.  You should really be using prepared statements instead of constructing sql.

Comment: Your posted code is way to messy to attempt to read and understand. The only suggestion I have is `"create components once"`. When you want to change the data in the model then you recreate the `TableModel` and then do `table.setModel(...)`. Next time I won't even attempt to read unformatted code like you just posted.

Comment: @camickr-thanks, i don't know how else to post the code as i'm new to this website and java programming

Comment: @KrishLakshmanan looking at the source code of your post, you just did not put any effort in the formatting. Just copy your code in your IDE, let the IDE do the formatting, paste it into your question and mark your code as "code block" using the available buttons

Comment: _but my jtable not getting refreshed after updating a row_ - no wonder, as the TableModel implementation is invalid (in not notifying its listeners on changes)

Answer (score 0):

you have near the bottom bottom

```
  stmt.executeUpdate(updateq);  
  DeptFrame x=new DeptFrame();   
  new DeptTableModel(x.getContentsOfTable());
```

1) I see a `stmt.executeUpdate` call, but i dont' see any `commit` calls.  do you have autocommit turned on?  i thought oracle had that off by default, so the execute is occuring, but then the new frame+model has the old content because the new content isnever committed?

2) why are you creating *yet another `DeptTableModel` with no references there?  it looks like `DeptFrame` is already creating one internally, so what's this second one for?

Comment: what value does `stmt.executeUpdate` return?  it returns the # of updated rows, maybe your sql didn't update any rows?

Comment: nope, it updates the value to the database perfectly but not to the JFrame or Jtable

Comment: why are you creating a new frame and new model?  early code creates a frame, and then does `setVisible(true)`.  the code im referencing does an update, then creates a new frame, another new model, then never shows either of them. Your setValueAt method also never appear to call super.setValueAt so does anything ever really get updated in the tablemodel itself?

Comment: Add this coding to the setvalue at try {
   ocrs.moveToCurrentRow();
   ocrs.updateString(getColumnName(column), value.toString());
   ocrs.updateRow();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }